# How many numbers below a product of first n primes P are coprime with P?

Tags: prime-numbers

Products of first primes are P1= 2; P2= 2*3=6; P3= 2*3*5=30; P4=2*3*5*7=210; etc.

Coprimes.
P1 : {1}
P2 :  {1,5}
P3 :  {1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}

Coprime count.
P1: 1
P2: 2
P3: 8
Pn: Cn
What is the sequence of coprime count Cn?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $C3= (2-1)(3-1)(5-1)$  This is not a coincidence.  $\frac 12$ of the numbers are odd, $\frac 23$ do not have a factor $3$, and $\frac 45$ do not have a factor $5$.  So $Cn$ is the product of one less than each prime up to the $n^{th}$